# Linux USB Driver Compilation

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, drivers

I'm using Linux Mint 15. When I try to compile the EXAR UART driver file version for kernel v3.5.0 and later provided here:
http://www.exar.com/connectivity/uart-and-bridging-solutions/usb-uarts/xr21v1410

I get the following error:

```
v@lenovo-linux ~/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak $ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  LD      /home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/vizzini.o
/home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/vizzini.c: In function ‘xr21v141x_tty_set_termios’:
/home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/vizzini.c:1104:22: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct ktermios’)
make[2]: *** [/home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/vizzini.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I usually first try to find some forum on their website and ask there. If this does not work I try to fix it myself, but there are usually more errors like this and I give up after several of them.

To fix this one:

1. go to /home/v/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-3.5-pak/
2. open vizzini.c
3. go to line 1104
4. there should be something like `whatever->whatever`
5. if not, post the line here
6. if yes, change it to `whatever.whatever` and retry make

Btw, why do you build as root?

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel interfaces change often. It's up to driver writers to

- either contribute their code back to the kernel, after which whoever breaks compatibility has to fix the driver;
- or make their driver evolve to keep up with incompatible interface changes.

The xr21v1410 driver was written for Linux 3.5. The message referring to line 1104 in `vizzini.c` indicates that a variable of a structure type is being used. Looking at the source, this is `tty->termios` where `tty` is of type [`tty_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty.h?v=3.7#L226). Around Linux 3.6, the pointer changed to become a struct inside another struct.

You can try fixing this by changing `tty->termios` to `tty.termios` throughout the code. However this is unlikely to be the only problem. You should contact the manufacturer and request an updated driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your answers, and in fact, rewriting this line fixes the issue:

```
//  cflag = tty->termios->c_cflag;
cflag = tty->termios.c_cflag;
```

The vizzini.ko driver compiles fine, and it can be loaded with insmod.